# Fetch calendar events between two dates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I need to fetch calendar events that are between two dates. I know only time interval, the user's email address and the calendar id. I do not how many events might be in calendar.

I found [CalendarView](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) in the API documentation. According to the documentation I compose the request as:

`/v1.0/users/{email}/calendars/{calendarID}/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-10-09T00:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-10-14T10:00:00.0000000`

I always get response with only 10 events. But I am absolutely sure that it is more than 50 items at this moment (and could be more, theoretically).

When I add `top` parameter to a query string I get the first `top` events:

`/v1.0/users/{email}/calendars/{calendarID}/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-10-09T00:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-10-14T10:00:00.0000000&top=100`

As you can see, using the `top` parameter does not solve my problem, because I don't know how many events and can't "hardcode" this number.

Could anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an old post, but just in case someone gets here from Google:

The response from the api appears to be limited to 10 items. It more items are available, the response includes an @odata.nextLink that can be called to retrieve more items (using the skip parameter). So you have to loop over the responses until there's no nextLink in order to get all events.